# Floating tcolorbox environment in another tcolorbox

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I defined a new environment with `\newtcolorbox` in the preamble. If I call it in the document I can use it. That´s fine!

```
\documentclass{article}

% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage[theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins, raster} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox,
blend before title=dash hang,title={#2},every float=\centering,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum{}
\end{tcolorbox} 

\begin{myfigure}{A tcolorbox figure with quite a long title}
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{modulation.png}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

Now I want to integrate the **myfigure**-Environment into the **tcolorbox**, like this:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
    \lipsum{}
    \begin{myfigure}{A tcolorbox figure with quite a long title}
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{modulation.png}
    \end{myfigure}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Why is this not possible? What means the error-messages:

- `Not in outer par mode. \end{myfigure}`
- `Undefined control sequence. \end{myfigure}`
- `Missing number, treated as zero. \end{myfigure}`

Can somebody help me to configure it right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You cannot use a float within a breakable box.

Comment: Thankyou. So what have I have to do, to get the result I want?

Comment: What is the expected result? If you have a breakable outer box you must disable floating for the inner box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a float within a breakable box. But as you allow options to be passed to the floating box, you can do the following (disabling float once):

[image: breakable box with float]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[theorems,skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins, raster} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,capture=hbox,
blend before title=dash hang,title={#2},every float=\centering,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum{}
\begin{myfigure}[nofloat]{A tcolorbox figure with quite a long title}
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{myfigure}
\end{tcolorbox} 

\end{document}
```